# Why does this assumption result in the correct answer to this problem?

Tags: thermodynamics

The problem is the following: given the equation $u(s,v)=\frac{A}{v^2}e^{s/R} $ that governs a system that undergoes an isoentropic process $(T_i,p_i) \rightarrow \ (T_f,p_f)$ such that $p_f=p_i/2$, calculate $T_f/T_i$.

First I made use of the Gibbs equation and the Euler equation to get the following:

$$dU=TdS-pdV+\mu dn \ ; \ U=TS-pV+\mu n \ \rightarrow Ud(1/T)+Vd(p/T)=nd(\mu/T)$$

a modified Gibbs-Duhem equation (the derivation is straightforward rearranging both equations such that they only have $S$ terms on one side). Now, I made the assumption $d(\mu/T)=0$. Rewriting the equation and finding relations for $p$ and $T$ from the partial derivatives of the $U(S,V,n)$ function, one can leave the equation in a form we can integrate directly and find the correct solution for $T_f/T_i$.

But... why does this assumption work? I just tried it to see if I got anything out of it, but I don't understand why we can make it. Any ideas?

EDIT: One of the possibilities I thought of is that the $\mu/T$ term is actually constant, and therefore $d(\mu/T)=0$. However, that doesn't seem to be the case.

EDIT EDIT: After more careful calculations, I got the result:

$$\frac{\mu}{T}=3R-\frac{S}{n}=3R-s \ \rightarrow  d(\frac{\mu}{T})=-ds$$

Which implies that $ds=0$. This would be this case for an isoentropic and closed process. I assume this means that the process is closed, regardless of the problem not stating it directly.

Comment: Don't know. Just a remark: It doesn't have to mean anything, that the result seems to be correct: it can be just a coincidence. // Can you vary the problem slightly so you can check stability (i.e. validity) of your outcome?

Comment: I do not understand why you should pass through differentials. You can easily get $p=p(s,v)$ and $T=T(s,v)$. From the second equation, you can obtain $v=v(T,s)$, insert in the first, and get a relation between $p$ and $T$ involving $s$. At this point, you have done. Please note that your previous question in much more compliant with this site policy than the present one, easily classifiable as homework-line.

Comment: @MS-PO Please check my new edit if you are still interested.

Comment: About your EDIT EDIT. I would say the other way around: due to the presence of an isoentropic process ($ds=0$), this implies, for the system described by that fundamental equation, that $d \frac{\mu}{T} = 0$.

Comment: @GiorgioP But if the process was open, wouldn't $s$ vary even if it was isoentropic? $s$ is a function of $S$ and $n$, after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this differently.$$T=\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial s}\right)_v=\frac{u}{R}$$$$P=-\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial v}\right)_s=2\frac{u}{v}$$So the equation of state is $$Pv=2RT$$The rest is straightforward.